# How to convert log files into Json format?

Tags: python, json, logging, scripting

I have a log files of my server data. I need to convert that data into json format. I need that data in json format to feed it into elastic-search.Help me with some sort of scripts which can convert this log data.

Comment: As-is, this question is too broad. How to do this depends on the format of the log files. You should at least show some lines from your logfiles in your question and what you would expect the output to look like. It would also be good to show what you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

Look into [lognormalizer](http://rsyslog.github.io/liblognorm/doc/_build/html/lognormalizer.html). You can specify rules to match log lines, and it will generate json for you, that you can further ingest however you want.